# Electron/Node Script breaks when using require to import file

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, electron

So I'm using this script to listen to some events from some buttons in an html script.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const $ = require('jquery');
const remote = require('electron').remote;
const paramsList = require('./paramsList');

$(document).ready(_ => {
  
  document.getElementById("min-btn").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    const window = remote.getCurrentWindow();
    window.minimize(); 
  });
    
  document.getElementById("max-btn").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    const window = remote.getCurrentWindow();
    if (!window.isMaximized()) {
      window.maximize();
    } else {
      window.unmaximize();
    }    
  });
    
  document.getElementById("close-btn").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    const window = remote.getCurrentWindow();
    window.close();
  }); 
  
  document.getElementById("home-btn").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    $('#content').load('home.html');
    paramsList.addElements();
  });

});
```

but as soon as I require

```
const paramsList = require('./paramsList');
```

the script stops working and none of my buttons do anything, i tried to change a bunch of things around but at least to me this seems to be what's doing it since as soon as I comment it out everything is fine again.

the file contains this function that's supposed to read from a file and add a bunch of objects to a table (not sure if it actually works since i never got that far)

```
const fs = require("fs");
const $ = require('jquery');

module.exports = {
    addElements: _ => {
        $(document).ready(_ => {
            fs.readFile('../config/config.json', (err, data) =>{
                const params = JSON.parse(data);
                params.forEach((element) => {
                    let textbox = document.createElement('div');
                    let text = document.createTextNode(element.name);
                    textbox.appendChild(text);
                    let checkbox = document.createElement(input);
                    checkbox.type = 'input';
                    textbox.appendChild(checkbox);
                    let container = document.getElementById('params-container');
                    container.appendChild(textbox);
                });
            });
        });
    }
}
```

I've tried requiring other files as well, but they all seem to break the script.

Also here is the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self'">
    <meta http-equiv="X-Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self'">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/index.css">
    <title>Hello World!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <div id="title-bar">
      <div id="resize"></div>
      <div id="title"><img src="../img/b.png" alt=""></div>
      <div id="title-btns">
      <button id="min-btn"><img src="../img/minimize.png" alt="minimize"></button>
      <button id="max-btn"><img src="../img/maximize.png" alt="maximize"></button>
      <button id="close-btn"><img src="../img/close.png" alt="close"></button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="sidebar">
      <div id="sidebar-btns">
        <button id="home-btn"><img src="../img/a.jpg" alt=""></button>
        <hr>
        <button><img src="../img/b.png" alt=""></button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="content">
      
    </div>

    
    <script src="../functions/events.js"></script>
    <script src="../renderer.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Also please excuse me if the code is awful, I'm pretty new to this.

Update:
I'm getting this error

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:964
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module './config.json'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\matss\OneDrive\Skrivebord\new\html\index.html
    at Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:961)
    at Function.i._resolveFilename (electron/js2c/renderer_init.js:38)
    at Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:844)
    at Function.Module._load (electron/js2c/asar.js:769)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1023)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77)
    at events.js:4
```

Comment: do you get an error?

Comment: enable `nodeIntegration` while creating the new BrowserWindow

Comment: My nodeIntegration is set to true in my main window which is the only window I have. Problem doesn't seem to be with node since i can still use node modules such as fs fine.

Comment: @Juanes30 Yeah, i posted the error i'm getting in an edit at the bottom of my post. I have no clue what it means though.